# Laravel Rate limit API by user with basic auth

Tags: php, laravel, rate-limiting

I'm trying to setup a rate limit by user on an API route using Basic Auth in api.php but it seems that the auth user info is not being passed to the `RateLimiter` as I get a error:

> "Attempt to read property id on null".

Here's my code on `configureRateLimit()`:

RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
 /**
 * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function configureRateLimiting()
{

    RateLimiter::for('getRequest', function (Request $request) {
       
        return Limit::perMinute(2)->by($request->user()->id)->response(function(){
            
            return response()->json([
                'response' => 'failed',
                'message' => 'Too many request has been made',
            ],429);
        });
    });
}
```

api.php Route:

```
Route::middleware(['auth.basic.once'])->prefix('v1')->group(function() {
    Route::middleware(['throttle:getRequest'])->get('/animals/{id?}', [animalsApiController::class, 'show']);
});
```

I've attempted to use `Auth::user()->id, user()->id()`, and `Auth::id()` instead of `$request->user()->id` but same error. Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm missing something?

Note: When checking `$request->user()->id` in the controller it shows up fine.

Answer (score 1):

For someone using Laravel 8 or above and sanctum for generating tokens.

The following code would help implementing rate limiting user wise where you want to limit certain users.

```
protected function configureRateLimiting()
{
    RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
        $rate_limit = 100;
        if(auth()->user()){
            $rate_limit = (isset(auth()->user()->rate_limit) ? auth()->user()->rate_limit : $rate_limit);
            return Limit::perMinute($rate_limit)->by(auth()->user()->id)->response(function(){
    
                return response()->json([
                    'response' => 'Failed',
                    'message' => 'Too many request has been made',
                ],429);
            });
        }else{
            return Limit::perMinute($rate_limit)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip())->response(function(){
                return response()->json([
                    'response' => 'Failed',
                    'message' => 'Too many request has been made',
                ],429);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
 /**
 * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function configureRateLimiting()
{
RateLimiter::for('getRequest', function (Request $request) {
```

> dd(auth()->check());

```
    return Limit::perMinute(2)->by($request->user()->id)->response(function(){
        
        return response()->json([
            'response' => 'failed',
            'message' => 'Too many request has been made',
        ],429);
    });
});
}
```

first check login the user

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Created 2 throttle limiter for my different api request.

```
Route::post('route-url1', [NameController::class, 'method_1'])->middleware('throttle:rate_limiter_1');
Route::post('route-url1', [NameController::class, 'method_2'])->middleware( 'throttle:rate_limiter_2');
```

Here is my throttle Limiter.

```
$rateLimiterHandler = function (Request $request) {
      return Limit::perMinute(1)->by($request->user()->id)->response(function () {
        return response()->json([
          'invalid_request' => true,
          'message' => 'Too many requests have been made. Please try again after a minute.',
        ], 200);
      });
    };
    
    RateLimiter::for('rate_limiter_1', $rateLimiterHandler);
    RateLimiter::for('rate_limiter_2', $rateLimiterHandler);
```